# get two option id in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want calculate a sum with the selected ID so I get all ID in different var then call them by `find()` my code is not work :

```
$(window).load(function(){
function doStuff() {
var uone= $("#ud").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'a';
var utwo= $("#ud").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'b';
var uthree= $("#ud").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'c';
var bone= $("#bt").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'd';
var btwo= $("#bt").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'e';
var getValue;

if ($(uone).find(bone)) {
    getvalue = 75;
}
if ($(uone).find(btwo)) {
    getvalue = 70;
}
if ($(utwo).find(bone))  {
    getvalue = 81;
}
if ($(uthree).find(bone))  {
    getvalue = 79;
}

var shw = $('#inputamount').val();
var total = getvalue * shw ;
$(".totalop").html(total);
}
$("#inputamount").on('keyup', doStuff);
$("#ud").on('change', doStuff);
$("#bt").on('change', doStuff);
    });


<select name="sucompn" id="ud">
    <option id="a">a</option>
    <option id="b">b</option>
    <option id="c">c</option>
</select>
<select name="ducompn" id="bt">
    <option id="d">d</option>
    <option id="e">e</option>
</select>
<input autocomplete="off" name="inputamount" id="inputamount" value="" type="text">
<span id="ttotal"></span>
```

Actually I want to create a result users input and select based. Something like when user select 'a' and 'd' then 'input=1' so result come = 75 .It will change when user change any option or input .

Comment: `&` should be `&&` right ?

Comment: @Hobo why are you using id's to calculate the sum you can get the selected value and do the sum

Comment: `gvalue * 10%;` wont work either.

Comment: so how to I calculate this %

Comment: This is [mathematics](https://www.helpingwithmath.com/by_subject/percentages/per_calculating.htm).

Comment: @Hobo you need to multiply with 0.1 using `gvalue * 0.1`

Comment: @Niladri ok I am trying now

Comment: @Niladri please answer my updated question

Answer (score 1):

You should use `value` attributes:

```
<select name="sucompn" id="ud">
    <option value="1" id="a">a</option>
    <option value="2" id="b">b</option>
    <option value="3" id="c">c</option>
</select>
```

And then access it via jQuery:

```
var gvalue = $('#ud').val();
```

If you'd like to overwrite it with the selected value of the other `select` element, you could simply do the same for the other one and overwrite it:

```
var otherValue = $('#sd').val();
if (otherValue) gvalue = otherValue
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my question

Comment: I think you don't clearly state your question. Check my update, maybe that helps.

Comment: Actually I was trying to compromise this result with both selection . I think your update is ok . I am trying it now .